# Python plotting dataframe with list cells using Seaborn Relplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe. Each cell in two columns contains a list. I want to draw a `seaborn`-`relplot` with two columns as `x` and `y`. I am running in to issue

**My code:**

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'v':[[1,2,10,20],[3,4]],'i':[[5,6,50,60],[7,8]]})
xdf['nor_iv'] = ['True','False']
print(xdf)
xdf = 
                v               i nor_iv
0  [1, 2, 10, 20]  [5, 6, 50, 60]   True
1          [3, 4]          [7, 8]  False

# Seaborn plot
hue_colors = {'True': 'red', 
              'False': 'green'}
sns.relplot(data=xdf,x="v", y="i",hue='nor_iv',
             markers=True,kind='line',
                       palette=hue_colors,height=4, aspect=1.5)
plt.show()
```

**Present output:**

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: how do you plan to plot the list? You can't plot a series that is a list.

Comment: @DavidErickson you mean, it is not possible to plot the list vs list? It is a new attempt.

Comment: What are you attempting to visualize with the list is my question I guess. Are those coordinates? If those are coordinates those should under x and y,. for first and second value of the coordinate, respectively. Then the hue or columns should be `v` and `i`, so you would need to manipulate the dataframe.

Comment: @DavidErickson oho! I see. This is a demo question and I just made it. My actual data frame is big. Each list contains a few hundred samples. No, these are measurement data. If a cell in `v` has list of 100 samples, then `i` will have list of 100 samples. These two are voltage and current data. I just edited the question with few more samples.

Comment: you can explode the list into four rows. Is the list relevant at all or just the values inside of them? Also, are the lists of equal length for `v` and `i`? That is important to make sure that explode works properly

Comment: @DavidErickson I just edited my question. All the lists in the entire data frame are not the same length. Some have more or less but at any instant, both `v` and `i` cells will have the same length samples.

Comment: if the data were structured differently, can you share how that data would look with more rows in exploded format in your question, because you cannot explode multiple columns when the lists at any given row in each column have unequal lengths. For example, in row 1, column v has 4 items in the list, but column i only has two. Same for the second row. However, it would work if the first row ahs two items in bothj columns and the second row has 4 items in each column. The length of each list has to be equal row-by-row for each column for `explode()`. Kindly create a sample dataframe.

Comment: nevermind ^^^^ I weas using a previous edit.

Comment: @DavidErickson That's okay. I edited my question. Now you should see it clearly. I appreciate you for consistently looking at my question and helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `xdf = xdf.apply(pd.Series.explode)`. Please note that you then need to convert the required columns from strings i.e. `object` to data type `int` after the explosion. Three ways to visualize below:

If you want an overlay (no rows or columns):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'v':[[1,2,10,20],[3,4]],'i':[[5,6,50,60],[7,8]]})
xdf['nor_iv'] = ['True','False']
xdf = xdf.apply(pd.Series.explode)
xdf['v'] = xdf['v'].astype(int)
xdf['i'] = xdf['v'].astype(int)
sns.relplot(data=xdf,x="v", y="i",hue='nor_iv',
             markers=True,kind='line',
                       palette=hue_colors,height=4, aspect=1.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want columns, you can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'v':[[1,2,10,20],[3,4]],'i':[[5,6,50,60],[7,8]]})
xdf['nor_iv'] = ['True','False']
xdf = xdf.apply(pd.Series.explode)
xdf['v'] = xdf['v'].astype(int)
xdf['i'] = xdf['v'].astype(int)
sns.relplot(data=xdf,x="v", y="i",col='nor_iv', hue='nor_iv',
             markers=True,kind='line',
                       palette=hue_colors,height=4, aspect=1.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

And if you want rows, then:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'v':[[1,2,10,20],[3,4]],'i':[[5,6,50,60],[7,8]]})
xdf['nor_iv'] = ['True','False']
xdf = xdf.apply(pd.Series.explode)
xdf['v'] = xdf['v'].astype(int)
xdf['i'] = xdf['v'].astype(int)
sns.relplot(data=xdf,x="v", y="i",row='nor_iv', hue='nor_iv',
             markers=True,kind='line',
                       palette=hue_colors,height=4, aspect=1.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: A quick question: my original data frame has the lists as string, example, `xdf['v'].loc[0] = '1,2,10,20'`. So, how do I convert it to a list?

Comment: @Mainland `xdf['v'] = xdf['v'].str.split(',')`

Comment: Thanks a ton. It is resolved. You have no idea the kind of impact this plot is going to have on our project. Thanks a lot again for spending your time to help me.